# Typescript intelisense on default extends <N extends Ns = Default>

Tags: typescript

How to add proper intellisense when adding a default value?

given:

```js
type Ns = "foo" | "bar"
function translate<N extends Ns = "foo">(ns?: N) {
    return ns || "foo"
};
```

I would like to have proper intellisense. Currently it will only give "foo" as only option as input. But I would like to indicate that both, "foo" and "bar" can be entered while "foo" is the default when nothing is entered.

See this example is when starting to type:
[image]
It indicated that the value can be either "foo" or undefined. Which is not correct because it can also be "bar".

If I type in "f" it gives me intelisense for "foo":
[image]
That’s great.

But if I type in "b" it *does not* give me intellisense for "bar" but I would like it to give:
[image]

However "bar" and "foo" both being valid inputs:
[image]

If I now remove the `= "foo"` part, the intellisense is correct BUT then it does not know that "foo" is the default
[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I add types so that the intellisense is correct BUT it also knows that "foo" is the default when nothing is entered?

Here is [the simple example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgzlAvFARAMwPYZVAPqgIwEMAnFAWACg0BXAOwGNgBLDOqYEouuAGyOAQAPDCgQAHoLoATBPAB8ACh4B%20AFywAlFADeVKAagkIwGiXY88%20dFgqUAvgG4qVBmzjAoxT8k7c%20AhCKmkA) I’m talking about.

And [here a more complex example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcCcEMDsGcA21wFMB056gBQElQBjAe1imMQgAsBLeASgCgSFxQATVAM2gFdFwAOQDKoALygARFDhIUNUpIDczUvDaFIqFKgAqMBMjTjQAHkahQg7KgAeaWO2zrINWAHMANBdC7QdhydQAG8fSwBtAGtUAE9QNyt4AF0ALhCwy1Ao2PjYUBc3d1T8qEKVTNAAX3Kq7wA%20HB9oADdoGmQAI0RUQWgAW1R4AAdoQkG063Ck73pxOvTLcBih1FAAEW4%20ARETJZXiLg5N-iFRANRHbGtQAH4IZdQDo54TnYn4Gq1wXkg8rl5YIRwAo8jJDDpTIJ-PYLkFrhINi9tsIGhkEDcJt5LLNQhUWOoICYcLMxPNJLZJKAQGYJAArXgE6CgHjRUB9YiESLM4iQaireDQVlPcC0Gy2fpDbqePmgLTQSikVZ0UAAd2gcXZWiIxD6krsoDg7FAxF4bCefTiVENGS%20P1BBuwOGiMTSzqeunCgiSJPmBQ8PmqjEDjGpAAVoO5ViKUKAGYMIAY5GhMI7CHBQB1Vq1XNAuqtDfFsCasDROMbDhbtWRIBQmPi2LB%20qhhCMxtgJLiE7IjCC0sEpFxiMRJGlJIPh7UfFRtJxIH2pB1oJARwul5TKkGVKpWPlUJBmnv9N2dCZNNo0EfwWhzJY3Yc9o9Do2Bi3RoMsfd9k%20m6%2024xUZYADyHS0qgQLoM68A4M%20zatoMszQI6d6fo%20oAwb%208FTDMW71oSEjwHuB6QJeSaoDg0iJj2ihMOA5HjpI9BAA) that gives you more insights on what I’m trying.

Thank you <3

Comment: Consider overloads: https://tsplay.dev/WJpgkN

Comment: @DBS You'll get an error since `"foo"` won't necessarily be assignable to `N`. For example, `translate<"bar">()` would be an example of why it should be illegal to do that. `N` is `"bar"`, but `ns` has the value of `"foo"`, which is unsound, since `ns` should be of type `N`.

Comment: @kelsny how would that work in the more complex example I shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a Typescript bug. When switching to 5.2 BETA all works as expected ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it in the return statement

```
type Ns = "foo" | "bar"
function translate<N extends Ns>(ns?: N) {
    return (ns || "foo") as N extends unknown ? 'foo' : N;
};
```

Then, if no argument is passed, `N` will be `unknown`, therefore TypeScript will automatically infer `bat` to be "foo"

```
const bat = translate() // bat is of type 'foo'
```

And, as the type of the argument `ns` is `Ns`, intellisense will autocomplete "foo" and "bar".

Comment: How would that work in the complex example?